# bootstrapTable: how to vertical align the detail-icon?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-table

I'm using [bootstrapTable](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table) and ran into the following problem:

In every row of my table a preview picture is shown so that the row height is greater than 'normal' and the content in the remaining columns is placed on top. I want to vertical-align the text/buttons/checkboxes in those columns. By using the options `align: 'center'` and `valign: 'middle'` for the columns one can achieve this - at least for the 'normal' ones. It has no effect on the columns containing the checkboxes and the detail icons ('plus'-icons).

I added

```
.bs-checkbox {
    text-align: center !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

to my css file and received the desired result. But an analog way for the `detail-icon` class went wrong. I found similar questions on Stackoverflow - but the answers didn't help me.

Has anyone an idea to fix my problem?

Here an example:

```js
var data = [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Item 0",
    "price": "$0",
    "preview": '<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg" alt="Lamp" height="50">'
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Item 1",
    "price": "$1",
    "preview": '<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg" alt="Lamp" height="50">'
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Item 2",
    "price": "$2",
    "preview": '<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/lamp.jpg" alt="Lamp" height="50">'
  }
];

$(function () {
  $('#table').bootstrapTable({
      columns: [
        {
          field: 'state',
          checkbox: true,
          align: 'center',
          valign: 'middle'
        }, 
        {
          field: 'id',
          title: 'ID',
          align: 'center',
          valign: 'middle',
          sortable: true
        },
        {
          field: 'name',
          title: 'Name',
          sortable: true,
          align: 'center',
          valign: 'middle',
          editable: {
            type: 'text',
            title: 'Name',
            validate: function (value) {return '';}
          }
        },
        {
          field: 'price',
          title: 'Price',
          align: 'center',
          valign: 'middle',
          editable: {
            type: 'text',
            title: 'Price',
            validate: function (value) {return '';}
          }
        },
        {
          field: 'preview',
          title: 'Preview',
          align: 'center',
          valign: 'middle'
        }
      ],
      data: data
  });
});
```

```css
.bs-checkbox {
 text-align: center !important;
 vertical-align: middle !important;
}

/* won't work:*/
.detail-icon {
 text-align: center !important;
 vertical-align: middle !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/vitalets/x-editable/master/dist/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/extensions/editable/bootstrap-table-editable.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/bootstrap-table.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/vitalets/x-editable/master/dist/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



<div class="container">
 <div id="toolbar">
  <button id="new_btn" class="btn btn-success">
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> New
  </button>
  <button id="delete_btn" class="btn btn-danger" disabled>
   <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Delete
  </button>
 </div>
 <table id="table"
   data-toolbar="#toolbar"
   data-search="true"
   data-show-pagination-switch="true"
   data-detail-view="true"
   data-detail-formatter="detail_formatter"
   data-minimum-count-columns="2"
   data-pagination="true">
 </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are actually going to want to set those properties on the table cells themselves, not the elements in the cells.

```
#table td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

This should do the trick.